# expand the list of items in dictionary

Tags: python

Consider the following dictionary:

```
import numpy as np

d={'a':[np.array([1,2,3]),np.array([4]),np.array([5,6]),np.array([])],'b':[np.array([5,6,7]),np.array([3]),np.array([9,8]),np.array([])],'label':['toy','ball','tiger','hull']}
```

Please note that key `a` first item has 3 elements in the array so key `b` first item has 3 items. The same happens for every item in both key `a` and `b`. Another thing to note is key `label` which has 4 elements , that is the same number of items in the list of key `a` and `b`. I would like to update the key `label` so as to have a list with the same amount of elements for every item in `a` or `b`. To be more precise the `label` key should look like that at the end.

`d['label']:['toy','toy','toy','ball','tiger','tiger','hull']`

So `toy` repeats 3 times because first item of `a` or `b` has 3 elements, `ball` only once because only 1 element in second item , etc.... Note that last item has no element in it, but I would still would like to keep the string occurring once, hence `hull` appears once.

I tried this but getting the string being repeated over itself:

```
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
d={'a':[np.array([1,2,3]),np.array([4]),np.array([5,6]),np.array([])],'b':[np.array([5,6,7]),np.array([3]),np.array([9,8]),np.array([])],'label':['toy','ball','tiger','hull']}
d.setdefault('newlabel',[])

for n,(i,j,k) in enumerate(zip(d['a'],d['b'],d['label'])):
    if len(d['a'][n]) == 0:
        d['newlabel'].append(d['label'][n])
    else:
        d['newlabel'].append(len(d['a'][n])*d['label'][n])

print(d['newlabel'])

['toytoytoy', 'ball', 'tigertiger', 'hull']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `extend` with list multiplication in the `else` branch:

```
if len(d['a'][n]) == 0:
    d['newlabel'].append(d['label'][n])
else:
   d['newlabel'].extend(len(d['a'][n])*[d['label'][n]])
```

Also if you're already relying on the structure of having a key `a` and `label` and you don't want checks, you can yust do:

```
labels = []

for i, label in enumerate(d['label']):    
    n = len(d['a'][i])
    labels.extend([label] * n if n > 0 else [label])
```

Comment: oh ok thanks. I don't understand why the list multiplication approach gives the right result however. I was expecting to form a list of lists [['toy'],['toy'],['toy'],.....]

Comment: I understand the confusion: `[x] * 3 == [x, x, x]` not `[[x], [x], [x]]`

Comment: awesome, i like the second approach. much cleaner than my code.